# Pipelining and xargs

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, find, pipe

I am trying to delete some .`class` file from a directory. So first I have tired to count the available `.class` file using the following command (after going to the directory) -

```
$ find . -name *.class | wc -l
```

Here I can understand the role of pipelining (|) - the output of the `find` command/process works as a input of `wc` command (please correct me If I am wrong). The above command works fine for me  and produce the correct output. But when I am trying to delete the all .`class` files using the following command with pipelining -

```
$ find . -name *.class | rm *  # case-1
```

then it doesn't works. It shows the following error -

```
rm: cannot remove `<a_directory_name>': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `<an_another_directory_name>': Is a directory
```

But when I use `xargs` then it works fine -

```
$ find . -name *.class | xargs rm *  # case-2
```

Now my question is **can anyone tell me why `case-1` doesn't works while the `case-2` works fine?**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that Case-1 does not work is that `rm` does not take the arguments via STDIN, it takes the arguments or the files to remove as:

```
rm file_1 file_2
```

Whereas in Case-2 `xargs` takes the output of the `find` command via STDIN and converts the filenames as arguments for the `rm` command.

Please read [`man rm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/rm.1.html) and [`man xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xargs.1.html) to get more idea on this.

Comment: Here STDIN means keyboard?

Comment: @Razib: Here STDIN takes the notion of data streams, STDIN is the file descriptor `0`, it is basically meaning here data being input to a program. Here the pipe `|` transfers the STDOUT of `find` command to the STDIN of the `xargs` command.